# Symfony adding element to form collection in PRE_SUBMIT event

Tags: php, symfony

Is there any way to adding element to a collection field in a form in the PRE_SUBMIT eventListner?

I have this (form1):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('file',
              'file',
              array(
                    'data_class' => null,
                    'mapped' => false, //il campo non è mappato (il file non è blob ma sta su filesistem)
                    //'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
                    'render_required_asterisk' => true,
              )

        )
        ->add('name',
              'text',
               array(
                    'label' => 'Nome documento',
                    'required' => true,
                    'render_required_asterisk' => true,
                    'mapped' => 'name'
               )
        )
        ->add('document_category',
              'entity',
               array(
                'property' => 'name', //valore da visualizzare nel form 
                'mapped' => 'document_category',
                'class' => 'docliteBundle:Document\documentCategory', //Classe da dove deve prendere i dati
                'multiple' => false, //E' possibile la selezione di un solo campo 
                'expanded' => false, //Per rendere un campo select
                'empty_value' => 'Selezionare una categoria documento', //questo sarà impostato all'inizio ed identifica la voce vuoto
                'label' => 'Categoria documento', //label del campo
                'required' => true, //la selezione del campo è obbligatoria
                'render_required_asterisk' => true, //visualizza asterisco di campo obbligatorio
               )
        )
        ->add('attributes_rel',
                'collection',
                array(
                        'type' => new documentAttributeRelType(),
                        'label' => false,
                        'mapped' => 'attributes_rel',
                        'allow_add' => true,
                        'show_legend' => false,
                        'allow_delete' => true,
                )
        );
```

the documentAttributeRelType (form2):

```
$builder
        ->add('dynamic_attribute',
              'entity',
               array(
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'class' => 'docliteBundle:Document\dynamicAttribute',
                    'mapped' => 'dynamic_attribute',
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'expanded' => false,
                    'label' => 'Attributo',
                    'required' => true,
                    'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
               )
        )
        ->add('value',
              'choice',
              array(
                'mapped' => 'value',
              )
        )
    ;
```

In the Form1 is defined the Listner:

```
 $builder->get('attributes_rel')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function(FormEvent $event){
                $data = $event->getData();

                $rel = array();
                $rel['dynamic_attribute'] = '1';
                array_push($data, $rel);
                $event->setData($data);
            });
```

But this adding element is not mapped and not appear in the view:

```
    {% for attribute in form.attributes_rel %}
        <div data-attribute_row>
            {{ form_row(attribute.dynamic_attribute) }}
            {{ form_row(attribute.value) }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, and as you already seem to know that you need the PRE_SUBMIT event, I guess that you're actually stuck with something more specific?
Read
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#submitting-a-form-formevents-pre-submit-formevents-submit-and-formevents-post-submit

And for a more practical aproach, look into this:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

And if you still have problems, please be more specific in your question.

Comment: exactly ,
the form has a field collection consists of an entity and a value .
Pre_submit event would add an element to this collection . As you can see in the example below, if you manually add the element in the array that happens :
PRE_SUBMIT event is correctly added the third element

SUBMIT event is not mapped to the third element , therefore I can not see it in the form .

I do not know if I was clear . Ask me if you ulterirori doubts . Thank you for availability.

Comment: Finally I solve it!!!!!
To set fileld collection in eventLister, the data must be set in PRE_SUBMIT but not in entity, directly in view with:
  $builder->addEventListener(
          FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
          function(FormEvent $event){
           $d = $event->getData();
           $d['attributes_rel'] = array(
             array('dynamic_attribute'=>2),
             array('dynamic_attribute'=>3),
             array('dynamic_attribute'=>1),
           );
           $event->setData($d);
        });

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find this useful for your situation, how to manipulate field options on PRE_SUBMIT event:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $pageId = $data['page_id'];

    $newOptions = $this->myManager->getPages();

    // change form field
    $form->add('page_id', 'choice', array(
        'label'         => 'Select a page',
        'choices'       => $newOptions,
        'required'      => true,
        'placeholder'   => 'Select a page',
        'attr'          => array('class' => 'form-control')
    ));

    $form->getData()->setPageId($pageId);
});
```

Comment: thanks but in my case I have a collection field already set in the form . Should I add an item to this collection dynamically without using any button in the client. Thanks I

Comment: Use POST_SET_DATA event to add new item after the default ones were already set

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need to add this new item in one of PRE_SUBMIT, SUBMIT or POST_SUBMIT because depends from the document_category field. In my view i have already made the ajax call when category value changed but if I change any value for the entity in POST_SUBMIT this changed value not appear in view.