# Dynamically modify form preset choices to pass validation in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I want to be able to dynamically add entities without having them preset in the choices option for EntityType form type. I need to modify available choices, because otherwise `invalid value` error pops up.

```
class MyImageType extends AbstractType {
    public function __construct($em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'class' => 'stuff/MyImage',
            'choice_label' => 'id',
            'multiple' => true,
            'choices' => [],
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        //
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return EntityType::class;
    }
}
```

and I'm using it like this:

```
$builder->add('images', 'stuff\MyImage\Form\Type\MyImageType')
```

the html generated looks like this:

```
<select id="product_images" name="product[images][]" required="required" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

I'm executing some ajax calls to create entity and append the id to the dropdown like so:

```
<select id="product_images" name="product[images][]" required="required" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="88" selected="selected">88</option>
</select>
```

`88` is existing ID for existing entity.

If I submit the form after that, `invalid value` error shows up, because `88` is not in the preset `choices` for this entity type. So I need to add `88` in the available choices.

If this was a child of a form (Symfony\Component\Form\Form), I could do this on `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT`

```
//..
$img = $em->findOneById(88);
$form->add('images', [
    'class' => 'stuff/MyImage',
    'choice_label' => 'id',
    'multiple' => true,
    'choices' => [$img],
]);
```

but in my case I want to do it inside `MyImageType` class to encapsulate the class. Can you give me directions how to do it? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

In the process of writing this question I've found a solution to this. In the event I can update the field like so:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use($em) {
    $form = $$event->getForm();
    $form->getParent()->add('images', EntityType::class, $options);
}
```

Still I don't want to answer my own question, because maybe there is a better way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting value using set method of the object before passing it to your form ?

Comment: I suggested a similar solution a while ago to an user that had a problem like yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981609/symfony-adding-element-to-form-collection-in-pre-submit-event/27982025#comment44356045_27982025

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on my [FormBundle](https://github.com/Alsatian67/FormBundle/blob/master/Form/Extensions/ExtensibleSubscriber.php).

To resolve that, I hook in the PRE_SUBMIT FormEvent, and I recreate the child injecting the submitted choices to the new 'choices' option.

If you want your field to be populated when editing an entity, you have to do the same in PRE_SET_DATA.

**Caution**

Doing it so, each existing submitted entity will be a valid value.
If only a part of the entities are selectable you should also add a constraint to your field.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, and I have seen your last edit, but I think your solution should look more like this (to also preserve the "embedded" form name and its class, because it's not an EntityType but a custom type.

I added this piece of code in my custom form type:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($options): void {
            $data = $event->getData();
            if ($data === null || $data === []) {
                return;
            }

            // The following works with both "multiple" true and false.
            $entityIds = is_array($data) ? $data : [$data];
            $entities = $this->yourInjectedRepository->findByIds($entityIds);

            // Self-replace this form in its parent with a clone (same name and options) that has the needed choices.
            $options['choices'] = $entities;
            $event->getForm()->getParent()->add(
                $event->getForm()->getName(),
                self::class,
                $options
            );
        });
    }
```